# Generic container factory

Tags: java, generics

In my code I have a generic Container interface. The container has a factory object, and the containers type is determined by the factory.

Like so:

```
public class HardGenerics {
    public static Container<String> stringContainer(Function<Supplier<String>,Container<String>> factory) {
        return factory.apply(() -> "");
    }

    public static Container<Integer> integerContainer(Function<Supplier<Integer>,Container<Integer>> factory) {
        return factory.apply(() -> 0);
    }

    private interface Container<T> { }

    public static class ListBackedContainer<T> implements Container<T>{
        private final Supplier<T> factory;
        private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        public ListBackedContainer(Supplier<T> factory) {
            this.factory = factory;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create();
    }

    private static void create() {
        stringContainer(ListBackedContainer::new);//extract single parameter
        integerContainer(ListBackedContainer::new);//extract single parameter
    }
}
```

**Question:**

I would like to pass the container factory (ie ListBackedContainer::new) around in my codebase, but I can't figure out how to type it?

**Update:**

So to elaborate on the problem. I cannot do this (or I can't figure out how to):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    create(ListBackedContainer::new);
}

private static void create(Function<Supplier</*what to do*/>, Container</*what to do*/>> factory) {
    stringContainer(factory);
    integerContainer(factory);
}
```

I would like to pass around a abstract generic container factory, and not the concrete ListBackedContainer

Comment: What's wrong with what you have here?

Comment: As you can see from the two comments and my proposed workaround below, I want to pass a single ContainerFactory around, but what type should it have

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Why is `containerFactory::create` preferable to `ListBackedContainer::new`?

Comment: @shmosel see update. I need to pass the factory around, as abstract, and only select the concrete implementation in main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible, so a reasonable workaround could be to create an real abstract factory interface like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    create(ListBackedContainer::new);
}

private static void create(ContainerFactory containerFactory) {
    stringContainer(containerFactory::create);
    integerContainer(containerFactory::create);
}

interface ContainerFactory{
    <T> Container<T> create(Supplier<T> itemFactory);
}
```

Not a lot of footwork, and it's more expressive than the generic type hell.

Comment: This is not a correct solution. `ListBackedContainer::new` is ignoring the factory's `T` parameter and generates a raw type warning.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why it generates that warning. Type inference works fine with a static factory method (`ListBackedContainer::create`) but fails with the constructor reference.

Comment: You can also avoid the raw type warning by instantiating the factory as an anonymous subclass instead of using a method reference. If you specifically want to construct the class with a method reference, you can create a factory factory, also instantiated anonymously, that returns `ListBackedContainer<T>::new`.

Comment: Don't get what you mean. I don't get a raw type warning with this code. It's just an abstract factory interface, that uses receiver type inference (or whatever it is called. The Type of the created Container is determined by the type of the receiver variable)

Comment: Interesting. What compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_73" AND IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 EAP